# External browser with intent, back key problem - Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm working on an app which launches an external browser with this code:

```
Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl));
startActivity(webIntent);
```

When the user is done with the external browser it takes the user back to the main `Activity`. The only problem is when the user presses the back it launches the external browser with a blank page, since the `startActivity` launches an `Activity` which I seem to have no control over.

How do I make the back key ignore the browser, or more importantly how do I finish the activity that the webIntent launches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hrm I had a similar problem recently, maybe use something like:

```
intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

or

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
```

maybe ?

Well the clear top flag may not work, but look at the exclude from recents or other flags. Specifically FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY.

> If set, the new activity is not kept in the history stack. As soon as the user navigates away from it, the activity is finished. This may also be set with the noHistory attribute.